# Cardano-Wallet on LAN

Tags: wallet, cardano-node

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

That's all I can manage to get when making an http call to cardano-wallet on another machine on my local LAN.

Cardano-wallet is synced and I used 'serve' when launching the wallet and the port I specified is open and listening...

Comment: What wallet software and software version are you using? On what OS (WIndows/Mac/Linux)? What are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Apologies, I realize this is not really a Cardano-specific question - I am just very frustrated lol
 - So...using curl in a command line on the SAME linux machine where I have the node & wallet running, I am able to use the web api without issue - I just ran a v2/wallets to list known wallets and it works fine.
It's just calling from any other machine on my LAN I am only getting "...target machine actively refused it..." even though I have confirmed the firewall on that machine is inactive and the cardano-wallet process is reporting 'LISTEN' on the port it was launched to serve on...

Comment: I think it must have something to do with the host being configured when the wallet launches as the loopback 127.0.0.1 but that not mapping for requests to the ip of the machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--listen-address
!!! THAT was it :)
The default in the startup command for Cardano-wallet is the loopback address so of course I could not reach that from anywhere except the same machine the wallet was running on!
Got it - now connecting and interacting on LAN woot!